# Join query with multiple same column in one row

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, loops, foreach

I want to make this
[image: image 1]

and this is my query

```
SELECT 
    modules.nama_module,
    seats.from_seat,
    seats.until_seat,
    seats.available,
    seats.id_seat
FROM `modules`
RIGHT JOIN `seats` ON modules.id_module = seats.id_module
WHERE seats.id_day=1 OR seats.id_day=2
```

what should i do to make this?

[image: image output]

Comment: Probably a group by or a join somewhere

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Note that I've created two columns, one that lists comma separated seat_ids and the other that shows seat count. The seat count is all you need to create the view you show on the screenshot but I retain seat_ids to have the output similar to what you suggest:

```
SELECT 
    modules.nama_module,
    seats.from_seat,
    seats.until_seat,
    seats.available,
    GROUP_CONCAT(seats.id_seat) as seat_ids,
    COUNT(seats.id_seats) as seats_count
FROM `modules`
RIGHT JOIN `seats` ON modules.id_module = seats.id_module
WHERE seats.id_day=1 OR seats.id_day=2
GROUP BY modules.nama_module, seats.from_seat, seats.until_seat
```

Creating new columns for each new seat_id has its own problems. Creating column names, awkward querying ect.

[EDIT:] just added nama_module column to GROUP BY as I realized the times might overlap for different services (Am I right?)

Answer (score -1):

A group by and a sum is missing in your query

```sql
SELECT 
    modules.nama_module,
    seats.from_seat,
    seats.until_seat,
    seats.available,
    seats.id_seat,
    sum(seats.id_seat) as nb_seat_available
FROM `modules`
RIGHT JOIN `seats` ON modules.id_module = seats.id_module
WHERE seats.id_day=1 OR seats.id_day=2
GROUP BY seats.from_seat
```